# How to calculate currency string

Tags: php, regex, string, str-replace

I am trying to calculate two variables type "String" in php.
and I try all alternative but steady amount missing values.

example:

```
$a = "250,000.50";
$b = "30,000.00";
echo $a - $b;
```

I want to return value with same format ###,###,###.## -String -Decimal -only return same format.

Note: I try all the link format currency here...use regex, sprintf, replace, etc...
but always lose a digit because the example use in format en_US or EUR.

Thanks!.

Comment: what output do you expect from 2 string substraction? (note - they are not numbers, they are strings, like `"hello" - "world"`)

Comment: What you can do is converting $a to number $a = "250000.50";
$a_Int = (int)$a; you can read more about php string to number conversion in google and even in stackoverflow

Comment: @Lashane I write -I want to return value with same format ###,###,###.## - So I dont care if var is String, I need only return same format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this **function** for **easily handle**:

```
$a = "250,000.50";
$b = "30,000.00";
function currency($c=0){
    return preg_replace("/[^\d\.]+/iu","",$c);
} 

echo number_format(currency($a) - currency($b) ,2);
```

Comment: Thanks, :) is simple code

Comment: I am glad to see accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The subtraction on strings will auto-cast the strings into numbers for you, but you have to get rid of the commas first:

```
$a = "250,000.50";
$b = "30,000.00";
echo str_replace(',', '', $a) - str_replace(',', '', $b);
```

Oh, and wrap the whole thing in `number_format` to get it back to the comma format:

```
echo number_format( str_replace(',', '', $a) - str_replace(',', '', $b), 2);
```